# AWS Timestream: How can I measure query time?

Tags: sql, amazon-timestream

How can I measure query time?

Unfortunately, I couldn't find query time in AWS query editor of Timestream.
So, I Tried below SQL but it didn't work. For some reason, I get a syntax error. (If I exec for each sentence, it doesn't provide an error.)

Could anyone explain the reason?

```
SELECT now();
SELECT count(*) FROM "test"."test"
where time between ago(3d) and now()
LIMIT 10;
SELECT now()
```

Answer (score 0):

A query string can not have multiple statements in it, as such ';' creates a syntax error. You could use SQL tools like dBeaver or other that would display query time